# gcc error when using named addrers specifier __seg_fs or __seg_gs

Tags: gcc

It is supposed that __seg_gs is supported in gcc for x86.
I have used it before, but actually I get the following error when I try to compile.
error: '__seg_fs' does not name a type

Some code that shows the use is bellow:

```
#include <iostream>

thread_local long int a=7;
__seg_fs int b=5;


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
#ifdef __SEG_FS
    std::cout<<"SEG_FS supported\n";
#else
    std::cout<<"SEG_FS not supported\n";
#endif
#ifdef __SEG_GS
    std::cout<<"SEG_GS supported\n";
#else
    std::cout<<"SEG_GS not supported\n";
#endif
    a=a+b;  
    std::cout<<" a="<<a<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

May be I miss an include, may be versions o gcc have changed ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that g++ does not "see" __seg_fs and __seg_fs , so the code must be compiled using gcc